# App crashed when drawing to canvas, waiting, then drawing again

Tags: java, android

So, I'm trying to draw to canvas like,

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
```

That works perfectly, even with nothing. It's when I try a timer of some sort, it crashes.
I just want to put 2 pictures, showing after each other, so Picture 1, then Picture 2 then do whatever else.
So if anyone can help?

Comment: There is no error, it just crashes.
I've tried, threads, handlers CountDownTimers...

Comment: there should be something in logcat that explains WHY it's crashing. If for some crazy reason it has no errors, then you have to step through using the debugger and try and catch the crash as it happens